# Old Epinion Dataset

Tags: data-request, social-media

I'm looking for the old Epinion dataset. The dataset includes 22166 users and 355754 social connections. It was available on http://www.public.asu.edu/~jtang20/datasetcode/truststudy.htm. But I can not find it on the internet.

More broadly, I am looking for a dataset which contains: user-item rating, user-user connection, and user-user trust matrices. unfortunately, the Epinion dataset on the trustlet.org website does not contain user-user connection. It is appreciated if you could help me finding the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Epinion dataset is available from this archived version of the page you have linked to:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160510014625/http://www.public.asu.edu/~jtang20/datasetcode/truststudy.htm (not the latest archived version!)

**Update**

[Currently](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~tangjili/jiliang_tang.pdf), Jiliang Tang works at Michigan State University (and not at Arizona State University).
New versions of the Epinion dataset are available [here](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~tangjili/trust.html).

Comment: thanks Stanislav. I wonder why do they delete that valuable dataset from the web!

Comment: @soroush, the whlole `/jtang20` catalog is unavailable, probably because J. Tang had left ASU in February 2015: https://www.cse.msu.edu/~tangjili/jiliang_tang.pdf